# Problemas inicializando el plugin de Bluetooth en PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap, bluetooth

Estoy usando PhoneGap y he intentado usar el plugin Bluetooth de Phonegap pero no he tenido éxito. Recibo el siguiente error:

> Error: exec proxy not found for :: BluetoothLePlugin :: initialize

Aqui dejo una captura de pantalla completa del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es el código que tengo en mi index.html:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y éste es el código de index.js donde uso el Bluetooth:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que supongo que debería hacer este código es darme el estado del bluetooth, si está activo o desactivado, aparte un botón que desactiva el bluetooth, pero a todo saltan las alertas de error.

¿Alguien trabajó alguna vez con Bluetooth en PhoneGap? ¿Por qué recibo ese error y cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Comparte el código que hayas utilizado y añade información adicional a la pregunta (¿Cómo no has tenido éxito?¿Recibes algún mensaje de error?)

Comment: este es mi código y el error que me sale en consola, te mando unas capturas, https://www.flickr.com/photos/143857613@N02/shares/0d71jd

Comment: lo que supongo que debería hacer este código es darme el estado del bluetooth, si esta activo o desactivado, aparte un boton q desactiva el bluetooth, pero a todo saltan las alertas de error